# How to express that somebody apologized on behalf of somebody else

Tags: phrase-requests, culture

To help describe my issue, let's imagine following situation:

- A foreigner comes to Japan.
- He is in the company of a native Japanese person. Suppose they are friends.
- During the day, the foreigner unintentionally did something against Japanese etiquette in public, which might offend other occasional spectators in public places like streets, public transport, restaurants etc. (like nose blowing for instance or saying something too loud in public transportation)
- His Japanese friend apologized to the potentially offended people **on his behalf**.

My question is: **How does one describe this activity in Japanese?**

Or in short, how to say: **He apologized on behalf of someone else**?

Comment: Did you mean "in place of somebody else" rather than "in spite of somebody else"?

Comment: Edited using correct expression. English is not my native -sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

～の代わり【かわり】に means "in place of ～" of "instead of ～". For example you can say 彼の代わりに謝る.

Another expression is ～の代理として ("on behalf of ～"), but this is a fairly stiff expression used, for example, when you make a formal speech as proxy for someone.